# Vaadin Grid: How to have a Ranking row

Tags: java, vaadin-grid, vaadin12

I'm using a grid to show rankings of players. The list is sorted by various comparators on the backend but there might be still scenarios where 2 rows have the same ranking. In the example below the first two rows should have number #1 and the last two should be both #2.

[image]

I implemented the ranking numbers as a column as follows:

```
rankings.addColumn(this::getRowIndex).setWidth("2em")
            .setResizable(true);
```

With this method:

```
private String getRowIndex(TeamHasFormatRecord thfr)
  {
    index++;
    return String.valueOf(index);
  }
```

Which it's a basic counter. The only way I could think of is basically getting each entry and find it's place on the list but I think that might be too heavy and won't escalate well.

Any suggestions?

**Update**
Here's the current comparator:

```
    Comparator.comparingDouble((TeamHasFormatRecord thfr) -> thfr.getPoints())
              .thenComparingDouble(thfr -> thfr.getMean())
              .thenComparingDouble(thfr -> thfr.getStandardDeviation())
              .reversed()
```

Comment: From software architecture point of view I think it may be wrong approach to try to solve this in e.g. Grid Renderer. Instead I would drop the implementation to business model level. E.g. creating DTO, which has rank as one of the properties and calculated by business logic.

Comment: I would do as Tatu suggested. let the rank be a property on the player class (or a DTO of it). I am almost sure you will need the player's rank in other situations too, and calculating the rank on the go using the grid sort order is sure to create problems just like yours. Don't get me wrong, what you ask *is possible* (put the `index++;` into an if-statement where you check for equal points), but unnecessary if the business model is more complete. You also don't have to calculate players ranks multiple times.

Comment: I don't think having it as a property is the solution. Since this is persisted to a database, each time a match occurs all entries would potentially need to be modified. That doesn't sound scalable.

Comment: Besides the ranking depends on what you are looking at so it's not straight forward. Depends on which game, on which format, etc.

Comment: That actually makes good sense. I guess your application is a little more complex than I thought - sorry for assuming otherwise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by changing the code a little in your `getRowIndex` method (I named it `getRanking` as it is no longer a simple index). The trick is to store the thfr of the current/iterated row for the next row to compare with. **If they have the same scoring, don't increment the ranking**.

```
// class fields
private TeamHasFormatRecord lastIteratedThfr;
private int ranking = 0;

private String getRanking(TeamHasFormatRecord thfr)
{
    // hasSameScore() will check for equal points, mean, and standardDerivation.
    if(lastIteratedThfr == null || !thfr.hasSameScore(lastIteratedThfr)){
        ranking++;
    }
    lastIteratedThfr = thfr; // store this thfr for the next thfr to compare to
    return String.valueOf(ranking);
}
```

This solution only works if you sort the grid beforehand and you don't allow resorting from user. I think you already did that.

Comment: It is sorted beforehand but I do allow for resorting. Otherwise it seems like it would have worked.

Comment: I am actually not 100% sure that it wont work after clientside resorting. Could be that it keeps the correct ranking. Probably worth giving it a try

Answer (score 1):

Create a TreeSet and add the point from each row to the set. Use the length of the set to return the rank.

(Add 10) {10} -> 1

(Add 10) {10} -> 1

(Add 0)  {10, 0} -> 2

(Add 0)  {10,0}  -> 2

Comment: This wouldn't work since the comparison is not only on points.

Comment: You could have the same amount of points bu way different mean and SD.